# Multi-Type members and dynamic registration form php

Tags: php, forms, post, dynamic

my system has different member types ( ex : Employee / Teacher / Etc.. ), the customer is basically a teacher, but my employee can be a teacher too, so what i'm trying to do is create a common registration form with specific common details such as name / email / gender / dob etc. and a check box to specify the type of registration that will redirect me to a new page with the remaining registration information of the specified party.

> **Example :** Checkbox=Teacher , redirect to **Teacher** page with remaining teacher details + the previous ones filled.
>
> **Example :** Checkbox=Employee, redirect to **Employee** page with remaining Employee details + the previous ones filled.

My purpose is making it dynamic because i will have many parties, my common form is basically pure HTML with post method and action to the second page, but the latter has also a form with values posted to itself where i make db inserts and automatic form handling (the remaining fields are already dynamic and they are retrieved based on table's columns).

I'm having an issue where i get the member type via $_POST, it's not working because the dynamic page has an action also to itself, the $_POST is not getting identified (Undefined variable), how can i work around it ? without changing the architecture possibly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since sessions also didn't work due to index.php concerns, i've used `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` which seemed to do the job for now but with the name showing in url of course, my solution so far.